# bash: awk all files that may have spaces under a directory, treating them as the same file

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, find

Trying to find all the files with a specific naming structure under a directory and all subdirectories and use awk to parse out the data that I want. I was able to get it as long as there were no spaces in the names of folders or the files.

I first use find to find the files and put them in an array. Then I use the array as the filename for awk. But the array treats any spaces as a different element so it splits up `/Documents/Untitled Folder/file.txt` into `/Documents/Untitled` and `Folder/file.txt`

Any way to push files that may also contain spaces? This is what I have so far which works if there are no files/directories/subdirectories without spaces.

```
arrFindFiles=($(find . -name "f*.txt" | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'))    
arrData+=("$(awk -F , '{if($9$10!=NULL) a[$9$10$13]++ } END { for (b in a) { print b } }' ${arrFindFiles[@]})")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you building an array, instead of simply piping the output of `find` to `awk`? Or the output of the `sed` command, if that is *really* necessary... If you want to achieve any sort of modularity in shell cmd lines, I suggest you go for files -- unless your data is *strictly* well-formatted.

Comment: Something like `find -name "f*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk '...'` might be a better plan...

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess.

Generate a temp file which list all txt files in current folder.

```
$ find . -type f -name "f*.txt" > temp.txt

$ cat temp.txt
./b/f ab.txt
./b/fa.txt
./f a b.txt
./fab.txt
```

then run awk command to find out the duplicate names.

```
awk -F \/ '{a=$0;b=$NF;gsub(/ /,"",$NF);c[$NF]=c[$NF]==""?a:c[$NF] OFS a;d[$NF]++}
    END{for (i in d) if (d[i]>1) print "found duplicate name: \n" c[i]}' OFS=" | " temp.txt

found duplicate name:
./b/f ab.txt | ./f a b.txt | ./fab.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first line to work with files with spaces, just put an eval in front:

```
eval arrFindFiles=($(find . -name "f*.txt" | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'))
```

For your second line to work, put the double quotes only around `${arrFindFiles[@]}`:

```
arrData+=($(awk -F, '{ if ($9$10!=NULL) a[$9$10$13]++ } END { for (b in a) { print b } }' "${arrFindFiles[@]}"))
```